# GetMapping After Postmapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying a `GetMapping` After a `PostMappng.` Postmapping basically does an Update.
What I am doing is, if the condition satisfies then no need to update but simply redirect to another page. But seem it is not working, It seems a GetRequest is not Possible from a Postrequest but I have read articles and even seen solutions on Stack but dont know why dont they work for me. Any help or hint will be appreciated

```
@PostMapping(path = "/campaign/services/migrate")
    public String migrateCampaigns(
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "campaignCount") int campaignCount,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "client-email") String clientEmail,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "campaign-id") List<String> campaignIds,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "selectAllCampaigns") String selectAllCampaigns,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
            Model model) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("Retrieving source and destination credential from cookies");

        String url = null;
        if(campaignCount >= 20) {
            url = "redirect:/login/oauth/login-with-eloqua";
         }
        
        String adminsEmail = contactService.getEmail(siteNameForEmail);
        String userEmail = cookieService.retrieveCookieValue(cookieDefinitionUserEmail);
        String clientsEmailAddresses = adminsEmail + "," + userEmail;

        migrateResponse = migrationService.migrate(campaignIds, request.getCookies(), clientsEmailAddresses);
        }
        //return migrateResponse;
        
        return url;

    }

@GetMapping(path = "/login/oauth/login-with-eloqua")
    public String eloquaOauthLoginPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return "login/oauth/login-with-eloqua";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get this approach, it's up on to you. I can see you have a class called HttpServletResponse, you can use a method that name is of the class.

Example:

```
httpSrvltResponse.sendRedirect("/login/oauth/login-with-eloqua")`
```